# Mocking pathlib.path object for Python unittest

Tags: python

I wanted to mock the class Path from pathlib. Let's assume that I have a function called functionX() where the Path object is being created. This throws an exeception. How I can make this work? My test looks like the following:

```
@patch('pathlib.Path')
def test_start(self, patch_path):
    patch_path.is_file.return_value = True
    patch_path.exists.return_value = True
    x = functionX() 
    self.assertTrue(x)
```

```
def functionX(): 
    p=Path("/some/non/existing/path/to/a/file.hpp")
    if p.exists() and p.is_file():
        return True
```

The output is the following:

```
AttributeError: type object 'Path' has no attribute '_flavour'
```

Can anyone help me?

Using pathlib3x instead of pathlib resolves the issue of the exception. But now I have encountered that the functions is_file() and exists() are not executed like mentioned in the return_value.

Comment: You shouldn't _need_ to mock it. If `functionX` actually took the path as _input_, for example, you could use test fixtures to assert on the result of actually checking file and directory paths.

Comment: yeah it is using it as input, i just wanted to show a brief example. Thats why i wrote that this path is not existing as string. The path was also mocked and is therefore no real path

Answer (score 1):

using this solved my issue:

```
@patch('pathlib3x.Path.exists')
@patch('pathlib3x.Path.is_file')
def test_start(self, patch_isfile, patch_exists):
    patch_isfile.return_value = True
    patch_exists.return_value = True
```